# What is an EDP coating and should it be removed?

Tags: paint, primer

Didn't see this question asked but after ordering new body components for a restoration project I noticed that many body panels, like an OEM tailgate and fender replacement I ordered indicate it comes with an EDP primer coating.

So thought to ask what is an EDP primer coating and should it be removed with 400 grit wet sand or the like? What is an appropriate primer coating that should be applied if removed?